# subdomain url using .htaccss

Tags: .htaccess

This is my website url http://mywebsite.com

I create an another website but this website's url would be http://mywebsite/mynewwebsite.com

Please help to find the solution using .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible. You can do http://mywebsite.com/mynewwebsite/ or http://mynewwebsite.mywebsite.com/ but not what you're asking.

Furthermore, I don't think you can set up subdomains simply using htaccess.